# ¿Cómo puedo traer información de una base de datos a React.JS?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, reactjs

Estoy realizando una aplicación con React.JS, y necesito saber cómo se puede obtener información de una base de datos (mongodb). Había oído algo sobre Axios, pero no lo tengo claro.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para comenzar primero es necesario que comprendas como puedes manipular datos desde React, usualmente para este tipo de funciones necesitaras almancenar la información usando estados y necesitaras un controlador como [Redux](http://es.redux.js.org/)
Redux es un contenedor predecible del estado de aplicaciones JavaScript.

Para usar axios necesitaras unc ontrlador de paquetes como NPM y luego correr:

```
$ npm install axios
```

Una vez los tengas puedes crear **acciones** que hagan las llamadas usando axios como por ejemplo:

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: El API la puedes crear con diferentes tecnologias como NodeJS, Laravel o Srping Bot.